# How to pause a Jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am making a really simple game, where an image moves as you press a button. The problem is, if you press, for example, left twice before the first anmation finishes, it does a second one. I want the script not to react when it is performing an animation.

Edit: I'll have you know, I'm really bad at coding, I'm just trying to make something small. All I finished is a bit on codecademy, so I don't know if this can be done with simple code. 
Clarification: I don't want Jquery to record any actions, when a certain animation is busy

Comment: Please leave out details about your game, and just tell us what you want.It's very confusing.Please clarify with details and we'll help you.Thanks.

Comment: You should be doing this with canvas, and basic input handling....not with Jquery animations

Comment: Without further details, I would suggest to simply use a boolean to "lock" your animation, or try with the methods `.on` and `.off`.

Comment: Instead of starting the movement immediately when a key is pressed, add the action to a queue (control the depth as desired; 1 or 2 is likely appropriate but there may be some games where "long sequences" are allowed). Process this queue when 1) the first action was added 2) at the end of a previous event (e.g. animation). It is the processing of the queue that starts the next animation. Using a queue like this avoids the need for manual locking and consolidates handling of actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using jQuery animations for a game, you should manually keep track of an object's coordinates and update the position manually. This way you can control where the object goes with absolute precision.

That said, in this particular case, you could try setting a boolean `isMoving` to `false`, then toggle it to `true` when an animation starts, and set it back to `false` in the animation's callback function. This way, you can tell it to only start an animation `if(isMoving == false)`

Comment: That sounds helpfull, can you explain the isMoving a bit more?

Comment: It's just a flag. You set it to true when needed, to false when needed, and check it when needed.

Comment: How do I know when an animation is finished?

Comment: jQuery's animate function accepts a callback that fires when it's done, I believe.

Comment: `var isMoving = false; $('.leftButton').on('click',function(){ if(!isMoving){isMoving = true; /* do animation, on animation callback, set isMoving  to false again */} });`